# Dragging object through two elements with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, calendar, draggable

I have a grid in a sort of calendar format, consisting of one unordered list where each list item represents a day and they are floated to be side by side. My app then has many events within each day represented by nicely decorated DOM elements. The vertical axis represents time, so moving an event further down the list item moves it to later in the day (similar to iCal). I am using jQuery draggable to allow the user to move the events around within each day.

Currently the user is restricted to adding an event to a day and then moving it within that day. Events cannot span multiple days (i.e. overnight) because they are contained within their day list item, using the 'containment' feature.

I'd like to know if there's a jQuery plugin or technique out there that would allow the draggable element to span multiple list items such that when a user drags it past the bottom of the current list item it starts to appear at the top of the next one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone's interested I started a plugin to solve this problem:

http://opensource.rotify.com/wormhole/

It's working fine for us but is pretty early stage nonetheless. Couldn't wait around y'know :)